# How to use the toggle function with click function?

Tags: jquery

I would like to create an animation when the user clicks on a button. There are two animate functions I want to do on click so I thought I would use the toggle function which swap between the two functions.

Now the problem is if I use the toggle function it is doing the two animate functions without click and also the button disappears.

```
$('#button').toggle(
    function() {
        $('#slider').stop().animate({"margin-right": '0'});
    },
    function() {
        $('#slider').stop().animate({"margin-right": '50'});
    }
);
```

How do I do the animate functions alternatively every time when the user clicks a button?

Comment: The `.toggle(fn1, fn2)` function is deprecated.

Comment: @Alnitak i used slideToggle() for another one but its still working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('#button').on('click',function(){
   var mr=parseInt($('#slider').css('margin-right').replace('px',''))==0 ? 50 : 0;
   $('#slider').stop().animate({"margin-right": mr});
});

Alernatively,

var mr=0;
$('#button').on('click',function(){
    $('#slider').stop().animate({"margin-right": mr});
    mr=(mr==0) ? 50 : 0;
});
```

Comment: It coming to margin-right=50 but when i again click it not going back

Comment: @raj probably because the output from `.css()` is in "Npx" format, not a number.

Comment: in any event, testing the current position isn't a great way to test this.  It would be better to have a separate variable tracking the intended movement direction.

Comment: @RohanKumar why not just test for `== "0px"` instead of that `.replace` call?  That said, I still think that's the wrong approach.  It'll do the wrong thing if the button is clicked mid-animation, because it won't flip the animation direction.

Comment: @RohanKumar Do you mind if i ask the explanation of replace. B'coz i would like to learn that:)

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks for giving a `shortcut` to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The `.toggle(fn1, fn2)` function has been deprecated.

The best alternative is to use a function that maintains a state variable to indicate whether it's an "even" click or an "odd" click.

In the example below I'm using an "immediately invoked function expression" to wrap that state variable in a closure (so that it's not global).  Instead of an odd/even flag I'm actually using  the expression `target = 50 - target` to flip the target coordinate alternately between 0 and 50 on each click.

Polling the current position of the element will not work correctly because it'll miss button clicks that happen mid-animation.

```
(function() {   // closure to hold state variable
    var target = 0;
    $('#button').on('click', function() {
        $('#slider').stop().animate({'margin-right': target});
        target = 50 - target;
     });
})();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/5daYu/

Comment: @raj `.slideToggle` isn't deprecated, but it'll only perform a "show" or "hide" animation.

Comment: sorry i couldn't able to add your name here

Comment: @raj yes, they're different.  `.slideToggle` _performs a show/hide animation_, with the state alternating on each call.    `.toggle(fn1, fn2)` _registers_ two "click handlers", one for each alternate click.